# Gnat GPL Gtkada: where did Gtk.Builder.Get_Widget go?

Tags: gtk, ada

I am trying to build a simple Gtkada UI from examples found on elsewhere on the Internet.
For instance [this one](http://lists.adacore.com/pipermail/gtkada/2012-September/004201.html).

The examples use:

```
Gtk.Widget.Show_All (Get_Widget (Builder, "main_window"));
```

which seems reasonable enough, but I cannot find Get_Widget.  The author of the example cited above says “eventually resorting to Gtk.Builder.Get_Widget in the procedure body.”  However Get_Widget is not in Gtk.Builder.  The only Get_Widget I can find does not apply to Gtkada.Builder.Gtkada_Builder objects.  The most relevant seems to be in Gtk.UI_Manager; is that the correct Get_Widget?  I haven't managed to make it work, if it is.

Even the [documentation](http://docs.adacore.com/gtkada-docs/gtkada_rm/gtkada_rm/gtk-builder.ads.html) says Gtk.Builder includes a function Get_Widget.  My question is, where can I find the appropriate Get_Widget, or absent that, how can I get a Gtk_Widget_Record to give Gtk.Widget.Show_All.  Or am I missing the point entirely?

My Gtkada is from gtkada-gpl-3.4.2-src.tgz, downloaded from libre.adacore.com on 5 June 2013.

Thanks a bunch,

Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GtkAda 2013 is using Gtk3 instead of Gtk2, leading to following changes :

1. Get_Widget is replaced by Get_Object : 
   Show_All (Gtk_Widget (Gtkada.Builder.Get_Object (Builder, "fenetre")));
2. Add_From_File profile is changed to a function :
   Retval := Add_From_File (Builder, GladeFileName, Error'Access);

Comment: Aha.  Thanks for that.  The documentation is not quite up to date, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

An implementation of `Get_Widget` typically returns the `Gtk.Widget.Gtk_Widget_Record` (or an `access` value of type `Gtk.Widget.Gtk_Widget`) for a particular `Gtk.Widget`.

The [example cited](http://lists.adacore.com/pipermail/gtkada/2012-September/004201.html) is a response to a [question](http://lists.adacore.com/pipermail/gtkada/2012-September/004199.html) about a regression in an example in the `GtkaAda` source distribution, which may be found in the directory `examples/tooltips/tooltips.adb`. The example calls `Get_Widget` on an instance of `Gtk.Tree_View_Column.Gtk_Tree_View_Column`. The implementation binds to `gtk_tree_view_column_get_widget` in [`GtkTreeViewColumn`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeViewColumn.html).

Note that "[Support](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html) for `GtkWidget` type values is still to come."